# PostgreSQL 13 sometimes works but sometimes huge execution time

Tags: python, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL implemented in my Python code and works fine in general but sometimes it produces very high execution time like `199655ms` which is insane. In the normal cases I'm getting 5-10ms execution time. I have lot of tables and values in them, but these measurements based on a table which is contains about 5000 rows.

My `postgresql.conf` file:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,and_some_other_ip_here'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/13/main'      # use data in another directory
                    # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf'    # host-based authentication file
                    # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_ident.conf'    # ident configuration file
                    # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/13-main.pid'           # write an extra PID file
                    # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - TCP settings -
# see "man tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_user_timeout = 0           # TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, in milliseconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default

# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#password_encryption = md5      # md5 or scram-sha-256
#db_user_namespace = off
shared_preload_libraries = 'auth_delay'

auth_delay.milliseconds = '500'

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:${sysconfdir}/krb5.keytab'
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - SSL -

ssl = on
#ssl_ca_file = ''
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 256MB          # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try           # on, off, or try
                    # (change requires restart)
temp_buffers = 16MB         # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0      # zero disables the feature
                    # (change requires restart)
# Caution: it is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
work_mem = 64MB             # min 64kB
#hash_mem_multiplier = 1.0      # 1-1000.0 multiplier on hash table work_mem
#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB        # min 1MB
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1       # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
#logical_decoding_work_mem = 64MB   # min 64kB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB          # min 100kB
#shared_memory_type = mmap      # the default is the first option
                    # supported by the operating system:
                    #   mmap
                    #   sysv
                    #   windows
                    # (change requires restart)
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option
                    # supported by the operating system:
                    #   posix
                    #   sysv
                    #   windows
                    #   mmap
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Disk -

#temp_file_limit = -1           # limits per-process temp file space
                    # in kilobytes, or -1 for no limit

# - Kernel Resources -

#max_files_per_process = 1000       # min 64
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Cost-Based Vacuum Delay -

#vacuum_cost_delay = 0          # 0-100 milliseconds (0 disables)
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1       # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10     # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20        # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200        # 1-10000 credits

# - Background Writer -

#bgwriter_delay = 200ms         # 10-10000ms between rounds
#bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100        # max buffers written/round, 0 disables
#bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2.0      # 0-10.0 multiplier on buffers scanned/round
#bgwriter_flush_after = 512kB       # measured in pages, 0 disables

# - Asynchronous Behavior -

#effective_io_concurrency = 1       # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
#maintenance_io_concurrency = 10    # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
max_worker_processes = 12       # (change requires restart)
#max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2   # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 6 # taken from max_parallel_workers
#parallel_leader_participation = on
max_parallel_workers = 8        # maximum number of max_worker_processes that
                    # can be used in parallel operations
#old_snapshot_threshold = -1        # 1min-60d; -1 disables; 0 is immediate
                    # (change requires restart)
#backend_flush_after = 0        # measured in pages, 0 disables


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITE-AHEAD LOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Settings -

#wal_level = replica            # minimal, replica, or logical
                    # (change requires restart)
#fsync = on             # flush data to disk for crash safety
                    # (turning this off can cause
                    # unrecoverable data corruption)
#synchronous_commit = on        # synchronization level;
                    # off, local, remote_write, remote_apply, or on
#wal_sync_method = fsync        # the default is the first option
                    # supported by the operating system:
                    #   open_datasync
                    #   fdatasync (default on Linux)
                    #   fsync
                    #   fsync_writethrough
                    #   open_sync
#full_page_writes = on          # recover from partial page writes
#wal_compression = off          # enable compression of full-page writes
#wal_log_hints = off            # also do full page writes of non-critical updates
                    # (change requires restart)
#wal_init_zero = on         # zero-fill new WAL files
#wal_recycle = on           # recycle WAL files
#wal_buffers = -1           # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
                    # (change requires restart)
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms       # 1-10000 milliseconds
#wal_writer_flush_after = 1MB       # measured in pages, 0 disables
#wal_skip_threshold = 2MB

#commit_delay = 0           # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5            # range 1-1000

# - Checkpoints -

#checkpoint_timeout = 5min      # range 30s-1d
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_flush_after = 256kB     # measured in pages, 0 disables
#checkpoint_warning = 30s       # 0 disables

# - Archiving -

#archive_mode = off     # enables archiving; off, on, or always
                # (change requires restart)
#archive_command = ''       # command to use to archive a logfile segment
                # placeholders: %p = path of file to archive
                #               %f = file name only
                # e.g. 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'
#archive_timeout = 0        # force a logfile segment switch after this
                # number of seconds; 0 disables

# - Archive Recovery -

# These are only used in recovery mode.

#restore_command = ''       # command to use to restore an archived logfile segment
                # placeholders: %p = path of file to restore
                #               %f = file name only
                # e.g. 'cp /mnt/server/archivedir/%f %p'
                # (change requires restart)
#archive_cleanup_command = ''   # command to execute at every restartpoint
#recovery_end_command = ''  # command to execute at completion of recovery

# - Recovery Target -

# Set these only when performing a targeted recovery.

#recovery_target = ''       # 'immediate' to end recovery as soon as a
                                # consistent state is reached
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_name = ''  # the named restore point to which recovery will proceed
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_time = ''  # the time stamp up to which recovery will proceed
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_xid = ''   # the transaction ID up to which recovery will proceed
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_lsn = ''   # the WAL LSN up to which recovery will proceed
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_inclusive = on # Specifies whether to stop:
                # just after the specified recovery target (on)
                # just before the recovery target (off)
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'    # 'current', 'latest', or timeline ID
                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_action = 'pause'   # 'pause', 'promote', 'shutdown'
                # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPLICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Sending Servers -

# Set these on the master and on any standby that will send replication data.

#max_wal_senders = 10       # max number of walsender processes
                # (change requires restart)
#wal_keep_size = 0      # in megabytes; 0 disables
#max_slot_wal_keep_size = -1    # in megabytes; -1 disables
#wal_sender_timeout = 60s   # in milliseconds; 0 disables

#max_replication_slots = 10 # max number of replication slots
                # (change requires restart)
#track_commit_timestamp = off   # collect timestamp of transaction commit
                # (change requires restart)

# - Master Server -

# These settings are ignored on a standby server.

#synchronous_standby_names = '' # standby servers that provide sync rep
                # method to choose sync standbys, number of sync standbys,
                # and comma-separated list of application_name
                # from standby(s); '*' = all
#vacuum_defer_cleanup_age = 0   # number of xacts by which cleanup is delayed

# - Standby Servers -

# These settings are ignored on a master server.

#primary_conninfo = ''          # connection string to sending server
#primary_slot_name = ''         # replication slot on sending server
#promote_trigger_file = ''      # file name whose presence ends recovery
#hot_standby = on           # "off" disallows queries during recovery
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_standby_archive_delay = 30s    # max delay before canceling queries
                    # when reading WAL from archive;
                    # -1 allows indefinite delay
#max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s  # max delay before canceling queries
                    # when reading streaming WAL;
                    # -1 allows indefinite delay
#wal_receiver_create_temp_slot = off    # create temp slot if primary_slot_name
                    # is not set
#wal_receiver_status_interval = 10s # send replies at least this often
                    # 0 disables
#hot_standby_feedback = off     # send info from standby to prevent
                    # query conflicts
#wal_receiver_timeout = 60s     # time that receiver waits for
                    # communication from master
                    # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#wal_retrieve_retry_interval = 5s   # time to wait before retrying to
                    # retrieve WAL after a failed attempt
#recovery_min_apply_delay = 0       # minimum delay for applying changes during recovery

# - Subscribers -

# These settings are ignored on a publisher.

#max_logical_replication_workers = 4    # taken from max_worker_processes
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_sync_workers_per_subscription = 2  # taken from max_logical_replication_workers


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# QUERY TUNING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Planner Method Configuration -

#enable_bitmapscan = on
#enable_hashagg = on
#enable_hashjoin = on
#enable_indexscan = on
#enable_indexonlyscan = on
#enable_material = on
#enable_mergejoin = on
#enable_nestloop = on
#enable_parallel_append = on
#enable_seqscan = on
#enable_sort = on
#enable_incremental_sort = on
#enable_tidscan = on
#enable_partitionwise_join = off
#enable_partitionwise_aggregate = off
#enable_parallel_hash = on
#enable_partition_pruning = on

# - Planner Cost Constants -

#seq_page_cost = 1.0            # measured on an arbitrary scale
random_page_cost = 1.0          # same scale as above
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01          # same scale as above
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005       # same scale as above
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025     # same scale as above
#parallel_tuple_cost = 0.1      # same scale as above
#parallel_setup_cost = 1000.0   # same scale as above

#jit_above_cost = 100000        # perform JIT compilation if available
                    # and query more expensive than this;
                    # -1 disables
#jit_inline_above_cost = 500000     # inline small functions if query is
                    # more expensive than this; -1 disables
#jit_optimize_above_cost = 500000   # use expensive JIT optimizations if
                    # query is more expensive than this;
                    # -1 disables

#min_parallel_table_scan_size = 8MB
#min_parallel_index_scan_size = 512kB
#effective_cache_size = 4GB

# - Genetic Query Optimizer -

#geqo = on
#geqo_threshold = 12
#geqo_effort = 5            # range 1-10
#geqo_pool_size = 0         # selects default based on effort
#geqo_generations = 0           # selects default based on effort
#geqo_selection_bias = 2.0      # range 1.5-2.0
#geqo_seed = 0.0            # range 0.0-1.0

# - Other Planner Options -

#default_statistics_target = 100    # range 1-10000
#constraint_exclusion = partition   # on, off, or partition
#cursor_tuple_fraction = 0.1        # range 0.0-1.0
#from_collapse_limit = 8
#join_collapse_limit = 8        # 1 disables collapsing of explicit
                    # JOIN clauses
#force_parallel_mode = off
#jit = on               # allow JIT compilation
#plan_cache_mode = auto         # auto, force_generic_plan or
                    # force_custom_plan


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

#log_destination = 'stderr'     # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
#logging_collector = off        # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
#log_directory = 'log'          # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
#log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'    # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
#log_file_mode = 0600           # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off     # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
#log_rotation_age = 1d          # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
#log_rotation_size = 10MB       # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'
#syslog_sequence_numbers = on
#syslog_split_messages = on

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
# (change requires restart)
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

# - When to Log -

#log_min_messages = warning     # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

#log_min_error_statement = error    # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds

#log_min_duration_sample = -1       # -1 is disabled, 0 logs a sample of statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only a sample of
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds;
                    # sample fraction is determined by log_statement_sample_rate

#log_statement_sample_rate = 1.0    # fraction of logged statements exceeding
                    # log_min_duration_sample to be logged;
                    # 1.0 logs all such statements, 0.0 never logs


#log_transaction_sample_rate = 0.0  # fraction of transactions whose statements
                    # are logged regardless of their duration; 1.0 logs all
                    # statements from all transactions, 0.0 never logs

# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_error_verbosity = default      # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] %q%u@%d '        # special values:
                    #   %a = application name
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %b = backend type
                    #   %p = process ID
                    #   %t = timestamp without milliseconds
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %n = timestamp with milliseconds (as a Unix epoch)
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %e = SQL state
                    #   %c = session ID
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %v = virtual transaction ID
                    #   %x = transaction ID (0 if none)
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_lock_waits = off           # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
#log_parameter_max_length = -1      # when logging statements, limit logged
                    # bind-parameter values to N bytes;
                    # -1 means print in full, 0 disables
#log_parameter_max_length_on_error = 0  # when logging an error, limit logged
                    # bind-parameter values to N bytes;
                    # -1 means print in full, 0 disables
#log_statement = 'none'         # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_replication_commands = off
#log_temp_files = -1            # log temporary files equal or larger
                    # than the specified size in kilobytes;
                    # -1 disables, 0 logs all temp files
log_timezone = 'Europe/Budapest'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROCESS TITLE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cluster_name = '13/main'            # added to process titles if nonempty
                    # (change requires restart)
#update_process_title = on


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STATISTICS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query and Index Statistics Collector -

#track_activities = on
#track_counts = on
#track_io_timing = off
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/13-main.pg_stat_tmp'


# - Monitoring -

#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUTOVACUUM
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#autovacuum = on            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1   # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
                    # their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # actions running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds.
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50   # min number of row updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold = 1000  # min number of row inserts
                    # before vacuum; -1 disables insert
                    # vacuums
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50  # min number of row updates before
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor = 0.2    # fraction of inserts over table
                    # size before insert vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 400000000    # maximum multixact age
                    # before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 2ms # default vacuum cost delay for
                    # autovacuum, in milliseconds;
                    # -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use
                    # vacuum_cost_limit


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#client_min_messages = notice       # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   log
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
#search_path = '"$user", public'    # schema names
#row_security = on
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#temp_tablespaces = ''          # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
                    # only default tablespace
#default_table_access_method = 'heap'
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#default_transaction_deferrable = off
#session_replication_role = 'origin'
#statement_timeout = 0          # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#lock_timeout = 0           # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0    # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age = 5000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor = 0.1    # fraction of total number of tuples
                        # before index cleanup, 0 always performs
                        # index cleanup
#bytea_output = 'hex'           # hex, escape
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'
#gin_fuzzy_search_limit = 0
#gin_pending_list_limit = 4MB

# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
timezone = 'Europe/Budapest'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # Select the set of available time zone
                    # abbreviations.  Currently, there are
                    #   Default
                    #   Australia (historical usage)
                    #   India
                    # You can create your own file in
                    # share/timezonesets/.
#extra_float_digits = 1         # min -15, max 3; any value >0 actually
                    # selects precise output mode
#client_encoding = sql_ascii        # actually, defaults to database
                    # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

# - Shared Library Preloading -

#shared_preload_libraries = ''  # (change requires restart)
#local_preload_libraries = ''
#session_preload_libraries = ''
#jit_provider = 'llvmjit'       # JIT library to use

# - Other Defaults -

#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#extension_destdir = ''         # prepend path when loading extensions
                    # and shared objects (added by Debian)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOCK MANAGEMENT
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#deadlock_timeout = 1s
#max_locks_per_transaction = 64     # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 64    # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_pred_locks_per_relation = -2   # negative values mean
                    # (max_pred_locks_per_transaction
                    #  / -max_pred_locks_per_relation) - 1
#max_pred_locks_per_page = 2            # min 0


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VERSION AND PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Previous PostgreSQL Versions -

#array_nulls = on
#backslash_quote = safe_encoding    # on, off, or safe_encoding
#escape_string_warning = on
#lo_compat_privileges = off
#operator_precedence_warning = off
#quote_all_identifiers = off
#standard_conforming_strings = on
#synchronize_seqscans = on

# - Other Platforms and Clients -

#transform_null_equals = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR HANDLING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#exit_on_error = off            # terminate session on any error?
#restart_after_crash = on       # reinitialize after backend crash?
#data_sync_retry = off          # retry or panic on failure to fsync
                    # data?
                    # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIG FILE INCLUDES
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# These options allow settings to be loaded from files other than the
# default postgresql.conf.  Note that these are directives, not variable
# assignments, so they can usefully be given more than once.

include_dir = 'conf.d'          # include files ending in '.conf' from
                    # a directory, e.g., 'conf.d'
#include_if_exists = '...'      # include file only if it exists
#include = '...'            # include file
```

Python connection:

```py
async def dbinit():
    global connection
    DB_SETTINGS = {
        'host': 'my vps ip here',
        'port': 5432,
        'database': 'db name here',
        'user': 'postgres',
        'password': "password here"
    }
    connection = await asyncpg.create_pool(**DB_SETTINGS)
```

This problem usually solves itself about 30 minutes later but I getting this about 5-7 times a day.

System informations:
Ubuntu 20.04
8GB ram (currently 37% used)
200GB SSD (currently 30% used)
Python 3.8.5 (lib: asyncpg)
PostgreSQL version (installed from apt): 13+225.pgdg20.04+1

- Repo: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/

Comment: Yes, sometimes queries are slow, it depends on what you're doing. Something with a kazillion self-joins is going to be brutal. Keep track of what you're running and monitor for slow queries.

Comment: To really troubleshoot this, it would be helpful if you could post: (1) the query that is givig the high execution time, (2) the definitions for the tables that the query is using, (3) the EXPLAIN plan that your database produces for the slow query.

Comment: I have a table with about 5000 rows and just query one row like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1`. Just very simple and basic querys.

Answer (score 0):

Might be little late but check out answer on here.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289130/postgresql-changes-same-query-plan-at-runtime

In short sometimes it has to do with plan_cache_mode parameter. try changing it to force_custom_plan.